# Could I say 'variety international'?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

Is this following sentence correct grammatically?

> Over the past 20 years, Thailand has become more variety
>   international.

I suspect 'variety international' is incorrect. But I am not a native speaker of English, so I have to ask people who are native speakers about it first.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question will be more likely to receive a useful answer if you use the **[edit]** link to tell us, in different words, what you are trying to express about Thailand. The phrase _"variety international"_ doesn't have any meaning in English.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct.

'Variety' as used in your question is a noun that means "the quality or state of being different or diverse; the absence of uniformity or monotony".

'International' as used in your question is an adjective that means "existing, occurring, or carried on between nations; used by people of many nations".

What I think you mean is that

> In the last 20 years, Thailand has become more internationally varied.

which means there is more variety of nationalities in Thailand.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you're asking. As PE Dant says, "variety international" has no meaning in English.

Assuming "international" here means "internationally" we can only guess at "has become more variety…" but one, tenuous, suggestion would be "more widely (something like known/admired/desirable/liked)" but that's very, very vague.

If you could find one or preferably more other ways to phrase "more variety international" the question might become more clear…